# Invalid HTML in jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a problem displaying invalid HTML code on my jsp page. I would like to show stored lines on the page (from the db) and they are included in my page as a String like this:

```
... loop    
<td><%= lines[i] %></td>
... end loop
```

But if the String contains broken html for some reason, then the rest of the page is not showed, only the source. Is there any way to show the invalid lines anyway and have the rest of the page displayed?

EDIT:
I haven't said it but looks like it is important, that these are inner mails, so they are not security threats but there are 3 kind of them:

1. Only text message emails (showed properly)
2. Valid HTML emails (showed properly)
3. Broken HTML emails (broken page)

So I think text/plain MIME type is not an option because it would broke the 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple solution i can think of is to use `text/plain` MIME type, and avoid HTML altogether.

Comment: No you just have to remove those broken/invalid lines.

Comment: Have you tried JTidy or TagSoup ?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty long for being a comment, but is much more than a quick answer. Your question is far to large to be answered directly, but if you want to reach your scope you have to

1. sanitize html code before storing in the database
2. sanitizing it before showing it as output

You have to achieve these steps by defining some rules to be applied before you store html (you might want to block users from writing js code for example).
(But this is a chapter a part, there are tons of html validator).

Once you have point 1 and 2, which in my opinion are fundamental you can output lines as you wish.

If you want anyhow to output those lines, you have to block all of them in a "*non render way*". You might be willing to use a simple label/panel which tell .jsp to interpret at compile and execution time the lines as mere strings so that they won't be part of your html output but rather a part of a specific component..
In this case you can spot errors (like tag element misspelling)..

**EDIT**

By the news you introduced I can just give you a few hints.

As far as this is part of a bigger system it means you have a bug somewhere that allows broken email messages to be stored on the database. Thus the problem must be investigated at a higher level introducing point 1, so you have to sanitize email messages at such point. (are them stored in a blob? or in a proper datatype? may the message be corrupted on database due to incompatible char set or other stuff…? we have tons of possible way to be investigated here)

On the other way, at the output stadium you have two options: either you trust what is stored inside the db.. or you sanitize the text before if output it in the jsp page. Both choices need a validation mechanism (for which I suggest a google search because, sincerely, I'm not aware on how to do it..).

Once you have such mechanism you could also run a sanitize job on your stored data (if and only if you are allowed to change its content) in order to have always clean messages/mails. But at first I would like to investigate the reason underlaying the fact that you have broken messages in your data base.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated the question, could you look at it again?

Comment: It's the very same reasoning, but this time applied to the whole email. So you need to check email's html + you need  validation rules for the mail structure and its meta content..

Comment: It is only a part of a bigger system so I can only validate the String after I get it from the database. But how can I validate it? Could you please improve your answer with that?

Comment: thanks for the update, I really appreciate it and I upvoted it but I still can't accept it as an answer. My original question is how can I display broken html on jsp page (I can't influence what they are storing in the database) and I see that some kind of sanitize job is needed, but I don't know how to do it. I've already googled it and found nothing, that's why I'm here.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate and I'm sorry if this doesn't help, but as I stated, this was originally thought as a comment.. :)